# python installation on ubuntu giving many errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, apt-get

I am trying to install python 3 to ubuntu and when I run the command I get this error

```
Preparing to unpack .../python3-update-manager_1%3a20.04.10.10_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-update-manager.prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-update-manager package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-update-manager_1%3a20.04.10.10_all.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-update-manager package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-update-manager.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-update-manager package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../python3-distupgrade_1%3a20.04.38_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-distupgrade.prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-distupgrade package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distupgrade_1%3a20.04.38_all.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-distupgrade package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-distupgrade.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-distupgrade package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../sosreport_4.3-1ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/sosreport.prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old sosreport package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/sosreport_4.3-1ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new sosreport package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/sosreport.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed sosreport package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-update-manager_1%3a20.04.10.10_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distupgrade_1%3a20.04.38_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/sosreport_4.3-1ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have searched a lot and tried to update packages and many commands but none of them works for me , can anyone help please ?

**EDIT**

After I run the command in the forum sent, I am getting now this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-is-python2 : Depends: python2 but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core : Depends: python3-distupgrade (= 1:20.04.38) but 1:20.04.23 is to be installed
 update-manager-core : Depends: python3-update-manager (= 1:20.04.10.10) but 1:20.04.10.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Ubuntu has included Python3 for a very, very long time.  What, exactly, were you trying to install?  Please show is the command you typed.

Comment: @TimRoberts the version was corrupted somehow and I could not install pip packages, that is why I removed it and trying to reinstall it, but I can not install a fresh version of it

Comment: You still haven't showed us the exact commands you typed.  And which Ubuntu version is it?

Comment: @TimRoberts sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip build-essential git

Comment: The problem is, `apt` and `dpkg` rely on Python to do their work.  If you add the `--reinstall` flag, does that change things?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196401/how-to-fix-python3-after-messing-it-up

Comment: @TimRoberts please check the edit of my question

Comment: And did you do what it suggested?

Comment: @TimRoberts yes I did

Comment: You have made kind of a mess.  I suggest you ask this on superuser.stackexchange.com.